# Is Heroku Ephemeral File System where I can write to $HOME and /tmp?

Tags: files, heroku, fileupload

For Heroku Ephemeral File System, I read in other posts that the location where I can write to are $HOME and /tmp?

Also, does anyone know how I can view files saved in Heroku Ephemeral File System?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

---

> For Heroku Ephemeral File System, I read in other posts that the location where I can write to are $HOME and /tmp?

No, you are not limited to $HOME and /tmp.

> Also, does anyone know how I can view files saved in Heroku Ephemeral File System?

You can [copy files from the dyno to your local machine using Heroku Exec](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#copying-files-from-a-dyno), provided you are using formation dynos (and not one-off dynos) and that you are not using a Shield Private Space, which I surmise from your posts is not the case.

The dyno ephemeral filesystem is really not intended to be used to perform or store work. If you're building an application that needs to save files, save them to a cloud storage facility like S3.